# Fastest way to check if image file is corrupt

Tags: image, matlab

I have several 100,000 images that were sometimes copied incorrectly during a copy operation. Therefore, before training a neural network, all images must be checked.

So far I just use `imread()` and if it fails, I use `try/catch` to write the path of the corrupt image into a .csv file.

This works quite well, but it is also quite slow. Is there a way to check if an image file is corrupt using a faster method than `imread()`?

Comment: imagemagick (or [`file`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/file)) and a shell one-liner -- voting to close since this isn't about programming but about general computer usage (managing files). it's also not about deep learning, so I've removed that tag.

Comment: You need to use the proper copy operation, one that checks the file is copied without error. This is what checksums are for.

Comment: i used checksum but the images are still sometimes incorrectly copied.. i don't really know why.